# url name for asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

```
 protected void Button_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx?name=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }
```

for example this code gnertates a page like

www.mypage/PageName.aspx?name=12

is the database the id number 12 belongs to a name called x

and I want my result to look like this

www.mypage/PageName.aspx?name=x

Where should I do the change?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the CommandArgument contains the ID? You could look up the corresponding name and add it to the querystring:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string name = ........

    Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx?name=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name));
}
```

Comment: why not? what goes wrong? do you have a bit of more information?